# How to remove many HTML divs + closing tags efficiently in visual studio code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

After noticing an unnecessary parent container in my HTML, I want to remove all of it in a headache-free and fast way. Below is a sample of what my code looks like. I want to remove the div with `class="remove-this-container"` and the children within are varied (I want to keep the children).

I understand I can highlight and use ctrl+d to select all the same divs, but how would I remove the closing tag with it as well?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="remove-this-container">
    <div class="random-children1"></div>
    <div class="random-children2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="remove-this-container">
    <div class="random-children1"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="remove-this-container">
    <div class="random-children1"></div>
    <div class="random-children2"></div>
    <div class="random-children3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the element navigation bar at the bottom of the editor to select entire elements, including their outer tags.

Comment: If that `.container` div is always there, you can select it first with `cmd + shift + L` and move all cursors to where you want to delete and simply delete them.

Comment: @konekoya OP points out that each occurrence has a variable number of children which would make positioning multiple selection cursors unworkable.

Comment: I thought "and the children within are varied" refers to the `.remove-this-container` div, not the `.container` div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Emmet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) has a command called `Remove Tag`

As you mentioned, you can use `Ctrl + D` to select all the occurrences of the tag you are looking for.

Using the command palette `Ctrl + Shift + P`, search `Emmet: Remove Tag` and select it.

That should delete the opening tag, as well as each closing tag for each of your cursors